# MinGW: Python enabled GDB on Windows

Tags: windows-10, python, mingw, gdb

I use QtCreator 4.6.2, which apparently requires Python-enabled GDB if I want to use it as a debugger.

I tried to install `mingw32-gdb-python` version 7.5-1 with MinGW installer (graphical interface), and I got `gdb-python27.exe` file in my `bin`. But this file can't be opened. I'm getting error saying I'm missing `python27.dll`. I have Python 2.7 installed, and said DLL is located in `C:\WINDOWS\System32`. Obviously, `System32` is in `PATH`, so it seems to me that it should be linked on demand.

Simply copying `python27.dll` to `bin` directory of MinGW throws an error "Application was not started correctly (0xc000007b)."

Running regular gdb (version 7.6.1-1) still does not allow `python` command (checked that in case gdb-python27 was only extension to normal gdb).

Did I miss some step here? Shouldn't MinGW provide me with `python27.dll` (it is a part of few other applications, like OpenOffice)? How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. I found that it was due to using Python 2.7 64 bit, when gdb assumes a 32 bit python installation. Switching to Python 32 bit solved the issue. And you shouldn't have to move python27.dll anywhere if you use the 32bit version.